# Calculates the width of a rectangle given the area and perimeter

Tags: python

Ive based the e1 and e2 sections of code as two halves of the google equation found when asking `calculate width of a rectangle given perimeter and area`.

This section of code is set to be part of a larger piece that displays the calculated rectangle in a visual form instead of using integers, however when i test it, the answer it gives is incorrect.

```
import math

print("Welcome to Rectangles! Please dont use decimals!")

area = int(input("What is the area? "))

perim = int(input("What is the perimeter? "))

e1 = int((perim / 4)  + .25)
e2 = int(perim**2 - (16 * area))
e3 = int(math.sqrt(e2))

width = int(e1 * e3)
print(width)
```

Comment: could you give an input and expected output

Comment: @KalyanReddy Ive updated the post to clarify a bit, but say that id enter 100 as an area and 40 as a perimeter it returns 0. entering an area of 12 and perimeter of 16 would return 32.

Comment: You divide perimeter by 4... So, 4 equal sides is a square. Any one side is therefore the width. Why does `+ .25` do for you exactly? Why is there a random `16`?

Comment: @cricket_007 the sections marked eX are a breakdown of this equation:    w = p/4 ± 1/4 * √(p^2 - 16 * a)  (a being the area)

Comment: On Python 2 your first calculation might return a bad result because of the integer devision which return a rounded down integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's recommended you name your variables better so we know what you're trying to calculate.

From the Google formula, you should just translate it directly.

```
import math 

def get_width(P, A):
  _sqrt = math.sqrt(P**2 - 16*A)
  width_plus = 0.25*(P + _sqrt)
  width_minus = 0.25*(P - _sqrt)
  return width_minus, width_plus

print(get_width(16, 12)) # (2.0, 6.0)
print(get_width(100, 40)) # (0.8132267551043526, 49.18677324489565)
```

You get zero because `int(0.8132267551043526) == 0`

Important note: Your calcuation doesn't check

```
area <= (perim**2)/16
```

Comment: Wow thanks, Im assuming that the check prevents any results that wouldn't make sense?

Comment: Correct. You can't take the square root of a negative number

Answer (score 2):

Here is the fixed code :

```
import math

print("Welcome to Rectangles! Please dont use decimals!")
S = int(input("Area ")) 
P = int(input("Perim ")) 
b = (math.sqrt (P**2-16*S)+P) /4
a = P/2-b
print (a,b)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to use this equation specifically, it'd be easier to just brute force it.

```
import math 

print("Welcome to Rectangles! Please dont use decimals!")

area = int(input("What is the area? "))

perim = int(input("What is the perimeter? "))

lengths = range(math.ceil(perim/4), perim/2)

for l in lengths:
    if l*(perim/2 - l) == area:
        print(l)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import math

print("Welcome to Rectangles! Please dont use decimals!")

area = int(input("What is the area? "))

perim = int(input("What is the perimeter? "))

e1 = int((perim / 4)  + .25)
e2 = abs(perim**2 - (16 * area))
e3 = math.sqrt(e2)

width = e1 * e3
print(width)
```

Comment: What did you change exactly?